# TCP video streaming: TCP throughput(rate) and RTT

Tags: networking, streaming, tcp, video-streaming

we know that a rough estimation of TCP rate is: WINDOW/RTT, where `WINDOW` is the min(CWIN, RWIN), CWIN is the congestion window size of the sender, while RWIN is the receiving window.

nowadays, the encoding rate of videos may be 1000KB/s(8000kbit/s), if RTT is 500ms, it needs the window size to be 2000KB. But we know that usually the receiving window size is below 64KB, there is a big gap.

so if RTT is too large, TCP streaming is not possible?

Is my understanding right?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, we just use [very large windows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_window_scale_option).  Per RFC1323, 1GB is the maximum TCP window size -- 2,000KB is not a problem.

Comment: You meant the RWIN will be increased by the streaming client when it detects large RTT? But for the streaming server, its CWIN begins with 1 MSS in slow start phase, it takes a bit long time to reach 1GB

Comment: @misteryes: The window can be enlarged [very quickly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_TCP).

Comment: how about the `RWIN` on the client side? will the client TCP stack increase the `RWIN` quicklyl in reaction to high RTT ?

Comment: Yes. It will as well.